# Overloading + operator on generic class in C++

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm trying to overload the + operator in a forest class, a forest being a collection of trees, and the + operator is supposed to combine two forests into one.  I have the following code as my class definition:

```
template<typename NODETYPE>
class Forest
{


    public:

        friend Forest& operator+<>(Forest&, Forest&);
        friend ostream& operator<<<>(ostream&, const Forest&);
        friend istream& operator>><>(istream&, Forest&);
        Forest();
        Forest( const Forest& otherForest);
        ~Forest();
        void nodes(int&) const;

    private:
        ForestNode<NODETYPE> *root;

        ForestNode<NODETYPE> *getNewNode( const NODETYPE &);
};
```

The following is my implementation of operator+:

```
template<typename NODETYPE>
Forest& operator+<>(Forest& f1, Forest& f2)
{
    f3 = new Forest();
    f3.root = *f1.*root;
    f3.root.sibling = *f2.*root;
    *f1.root = 0;
    *f2.root = 0;
    return f3;
}
```

I get the following error on compile:

```
|28|error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '&' token|
```

line 28 refers to the signature of my operator+ implementation.

I think to correct it i am supposed to add  to the return type, giving:

```
template<typename NODETYPE>
Forest<NODETYPE>& operator+<>(Forest& f1, Forest& f2)
{
    f3 = new Forest();
    f3.root = *f1.*root;
    f3.root.sibling = *f2.*root;
    *f1.root = 0;
    *f2.root = 0;
    return f3;
}
```

But that gives me the following errors:

```
|28|error: declaration of 'operator+' as non-function|
|28|error: missing template arguments before '&' token|
|28|error: 'f1' was not declared in this scope|
|28|error: missing template arguments before '&' token|
|28|error: 'f2' was not declared in this scope|
```

Can anyone help me with this?  I'd be very very thankful.

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating, then trying to return a pointer to `Forest` instead of a reference? And that function shouldn't return a reference anyway, there's nothing to reference: When you add two things, you generally end up with a new *value*, so return by value. This is *bad* addition, you're manipulating the arguments. (`2 + 2` surely doesn't change `2`!) Maybe you want a `combine` member function instead.

Comment: Allocating the new forest on the heap and returning a reference is a very bad idea.  Just create a local object and return by value.

Comment: Or use smart pointers if copying is to expensive.

Comment: Yes the code has lots of errors in it but that's why he is here asking how to do it correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key to writing operator+ is *don't write operator+.*  Instead, write a copy ctor and operator+=:

```
template<class NodeType>
struct Forest {
  //...
  Forest(Forest const &other);
  //...
  Forest& operator+=(Forest const &other) {
    // code here
    return *this;
  }
  //...
};
```

Now we add operator+:

```
template<class NodeType>
struct Forest {
  //...
  friend Forest operator+(Forest a, Forest const &b) {
    a += b;
    return a;
  }
  //...
};
```

And that's it!  Copying is usually straight-forward (sometimes by being disallowed) and it may be simpler to think in terms of += than + (you have two objects and mutate one, rather than create a third object out of two).  This pattern for op+ works with any similar type, and even for similar operators such as -, *, and /.

Comment: Taking the first parameter by value instead of const reference is useful as we're going to copy it anyway, but b should be taken as const-reference.

Comment: @CashCow: You're absolutely right and that's what I intended; it's rather late here, so if you find any more errors, you'll have to wait. :)

Comment: Note to those passing by, it may be tempting to make that `return a += b`, but this is enough to fool the compiler from treating the result of `a += b` the same as `a`, so no NRVO is applied (and in C++0x, it is not moved.) You can of course do `return std::move(a += b);` to help it out, but you're not really gaining anything.

Answer (score 3):

Operator overloading can be a good or a bad thing. Good when it leads to simpler looking code. Bad when it leads to writers either overloading with incorrect semantics (yet a solution that compiles) or where the intuitive way to use the operator leads to highly inefficient code.

Note the latter statement can apply to std::string too, which could potentially make large numbers of copies, and which is why the C++03 standard states that a string does not have to be stored internally in a contiguous buffer (in the old days they used copy-on-write references to and could store such references to both strings being concatenated until required. Subsequently it was found to be non-threadsafe and making it so was more costly than simply copying the buffer so now they copy every time and are inefficient again).

(Note that the C++11 standard which recognises threading and atomic issues ensures that the underlying does need to be contiguous and null-terminated to make read operations safe).

The correct signature of operator+ (in the case all are the same type) is as follows:

```
T operator+( const T&, const T& );
```

As a member function it would be:

```
class T
{
    // make public if necessary
    T operator+( const T& rhs ) const;
};
```

You can implement operator+ automatically as a template whenever operator += is available  with

```
template<typename T, typename R>
T operator+( const T& lhs, const R& rhs )
{
    T copy(lhs);
    return copy += rhs;
}
```

If you want to declare an overloaded operator of your template as a friend, this is the correct way to do it. I will show it with operator<<

```
// first some forward declarations, assume ostream already declared with #include <iosfwd> minimum
template< typename T > class Forest;
template< typename T > std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & os, const Forest<T> & for );

template< typename T> class Forest
{
     friend std::ostream& operator<< <>( std::ostream&, const Forest<T> & );
     //rest of class Forest
};

template< typename T >
std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream& os, const Forest<T> & forest )
{
    // implement
    return os;
}
```

You would apply a similar technique to any other external function you wish to declare as a friend to your class, i.e.

1. Forwardly declare your class as a template
2. Forwardly declare the method as a template function
3. Make the function a friend using <> before the opening parentheses denoting the parameters
4. Implement the function after your class.

Comment: Friend functions for op<<, defined in the class definition, are much easier.

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide a template arguments for all `Forest` parameters.

```
template<typename NODETYPE>
Forest<NODETYPE> operator+(Forest<NODETYPE>& f1, Forest<NODETYPE>& f2)
```

Also, consider making the arguments [const](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html) references to make sure you do not manipulate them.

There are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787143/template-friend-function-of-a-template-class) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297609/overloading-friend-operator-for-template-class) on stackoverflow regarding friend function templates. The [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.16) also has a page on them that explains some basics.

Comment: And remove `<>`. His code is bad, though, so he cannot make them const references.

Comment: Ahh, thanks.  I would do that, but the project requirements are that the arguments be deleted afterwards, for some reason.

Comment: @joedillian: This is bad. Operator overloading is a double edged sword in that it often leads to code that is hard to understand if operators behave unintuitively. Noone expectes `+` to delete the operands.

Comment: @joe: Don't let your project requirements influence you outside the project, for your own good. And kick whoever made them for me.

Comment: I agree, but professor's function behavior delcares it to act as such.  Meh.

Comment: @joedillian: Send him our way. Guy doesn't know what he's talking about...gr.

Comment: @GMan: As long as the operator+ in OP does not modify 'root' it is fine. I am not sure if I understand your comment right. It is OK to modify *f1.root even if f1 is passed as reference to const. Isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for those references in your edit Space_Cowboy.  I wish I had found that when i was searching the net for 2 hours. :-/

Answer (score -1):

You can define an `operator+` template as follows:

```
template< class NodeType >
Forest<NodeType> operator+( Forest<NodeType> const& f1, Forest<NodeType> const& f2)
{
    // Implementation.
}
```

Cheers & hth.,