# template class operators "unresolved externals"

Tags: c++, class, templates, math, class-template

In my class :

```
#ifndef __MYVECTOR_CLASS__
#define __MYVECTOR_CLASS__

template<class Type>
class MyVector{
    ....
    MyVector& operator=(const MyVector& source); //works
    friend MyVector<Type> operator+(MyVector<Type> lhs, const MyVector<Type> &rhs); //doesnt
    ....
};

template<class Type>
MyVector<Type>& MyVector<Type>::operator=(const MyVector &v){
    if (_d != v._d){
        _d = v._d;
        _deleteArray();
        _createArray(_d);
    }
    _assignValues(v._vector, (v._vector + _d));
    return *this;
};


template<class Type>
MyVector<Type> operator+(MyVector<Type> lhs, const MyVector<Type> &rhs){
    if (lhs._d == rhs._d){
        for (int index = 0; index < lhs._d; index++){
            lhs._vector[index] += rhs._vector[index];
        }
    }
    return lhs;
};

#endif // __MYVECTOR_CLASS__
```

Didnt include other non operator functions, because they all work fine.
Not a clue why its not working.

In source file:

```
int main(){
    MyVector<float> a(10);


    MyVector<float> b(10);
    a = b; // works alone
    a = a + b; //breaks
    return 0;
}
```

And errors:

1. Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class
   MyVector __cdecl operator+(class MyVector,class
   MyVector)"
2. Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

EDITTED:

added constructor.

```
template<class Type>
MyVector<Type>::MyVector(int size){
    _d = size;
    _createArray(_d);
    _assignValues(0);
}
```

Comment: This might be a silly question but did you include the header file that contains the class or was it part of the main source file?

Comment: You have a copy constructor for `MyVector` I suppose?

Comment: Also you should use a `const MyVector<Type>& lhs, ` for the left side value.

Comment: I included header class. Yes I'll add it now. Why I should use const Im copying object and adding values to it.

Comment: Yes, I everything else works fine. Only arithmetic operators doesnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to compile with [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17925711ce1dc931), you'll get this warning:

> main.cpp:15:82: warning: friend declaration 'MyVector
>   operator+(MyVector, const MyVector&)' declares a
>   non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
>        friend MyVector operator+(MyVector lhs, const MyVector &rhs); //doesnt

That should serve as a clue to what's going on. Change your code to:

```
template<typename T>
friend MyVector<T> operator+(MyVector<T> lhs, const MyVector<T> &rhs);
```

And [it will build](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ed147d2e3fd0cbf).

The friend function is itself a template with a template argument that is separate from `class MyVector`'s.

---

Update: Although the above does seem to work, after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1787143/3549027) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1297609/3549027), I'm wondering if this might be more correct:

```
// forward-declare class MyVector
template<class Type>
class MyVector;

// forward-declare operator+()
template<class Type>
MyVector<Type> operator+(MyVector<Type> lhs, const MyVector<Type> &rhs);

template<class Type>
class MyVector{
    // declare that the already-declared operator+<>() is a friend
    friend MyVector<Type> operator+<>(MyVector<Type> lhs, const MyVector<Type> &rhs);
 };
```

Comment: "// forward-declare class MyVector "is so I can define my methods in includes?

Comment: @Cirvis Forward declarations are needed to resolve circular dependencies. Here, `MyVector` needs to know about `operator+()`, and `operator+()` needs to know about `MyVector`. `template<class Type> class MyVector;` informs the compiler that there is a one argument class template named `MyVector`. This allows it to make sense of the name `MyVector` when it reads the declaration for `operator+()`.

Comment: If that's the case, why compiler doesn't throw any errors?