# Explicit specialization of friend function for a class template

Tags: c++, templates

I was reading litb's answer to a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1297622/955273), where he details how to create a **specialized friend function of a class template**.

I tried to create an exemplar which did just what he suggests (*code at the end*):

```
// use '<>' to specialize the function template with the class template's type
friend std::ostream& operator<< <>(std::ostream& os, const foo<T>& f)
```

It results in a **compiler error**:

```
error: defining explicit specialization ‘operator<< <>’ in friend declaration
```

Explicitly declaring the template parameter in the specialization doesn't work either:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< <T>(std::ostream& os, const foo<T>& f) // same error
```

On the other hand, changing from using a specialization to use a **friend function template** instead *does* work:

```
template<typename U>
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const foo<U>& f) // this works
```

So my questions are:

- what is causing the first error?
- how can I explicitly specialize the `ostream operator` for the surrounding class template specialization?

**Exemplar code below:**

```
#include <iostream>

// fwd declarations
template<typename T> struct foo;
template<typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const foo<T>&);

template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    foo(T val)
        : _val(val)
    {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<< <>(std::ostream& os, const foo<T>& f) // error line
    //template<typename U>
    //friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const foo<U>& f) // this works
    {
        return os << "val=" << f._val;
    }

    T _val;
};


int main()
{
    foo<std::string> f("hello world");
    std::cout << f << std::endl;
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In litb's example, he's just declaring the specialization as a friend in the class. He's not **defining** the specialization, which is what your code's doing. You're not allowed to define a specialization in a class declaration (or any non-namespace scope).

What you need is something like:

```
template <class T>
class foo;

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const foo<T>& f)
{
    return os << "val=" << f._val;
}

template<typename T> 
struct foo
{
    // ...
private:
    friend std::ostream& operator<< <>(std::ostream& os, const foo<T>& f);
    T _val;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 choices:

Remove fwd declarations and define everything in class.

**Example**

```
template <typename U>
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const foo<U>& f) // this works
{
    return os << "val=" << f._val;
}
```

Define friend function outside of the class.

**Example**

```
template<typename T> struct foo;
template<typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const foo<T>&);

template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    foo(T val)
        : _val(val)
    {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<< <>(std::ostream& os, const foo<T>& f);

    T _val;
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const foo<T>& f)
{
       return os << "val=" << f._val;
}
```

Comment: Defining the friend function outside of the class will not allow me to specialise on the type being used to instantiate the original class template.

Comment: Removing fwd declarations makes no difference - I still can't use the class template's type as a specialisation to the friend function template. (Now the error is `declaration of ‘operator<<’ as non-function`)

Comment: Thanks Jesse - with your edits I now see what you were suggesting.