# ToString for templated linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, stdout

Here's my code:

```
template<typename T>
class list {                                               
    private:                                               
        node<T>* head;                                     
        node<T>* tail;                                     
        int len;                                           
    public:                                                
        list(){                                            
            this->len = 0;                                 
            this->head = this->tail = 0;                   
        }                                                  
        ~list(){                                           
            node<T>* n = this->head;                       
            if (!n) return;                                
            node<T>* t = NULL;                             
            while (n){                                     
                t = n->next;                               
                delete n;                                  
                n = t;                                     
            }                                              
        }                                                  

        /* other stuff */

        ostream& operator<<(ostream &o, const list<T>& l) {
            node<T>* t = l.head;                           
            while (t){                                     
                strm << *(t->value);                       
                if (!t->next) break;                       
                strm << ", ";                              
                t = t->next;                               
            }                                              
            return strm;                                   
        }                                                  
};
```

I get the following compile error:

```
rm bin *.o -f
g++ -g -Wall main.cpp -o bin
main.cpp:110: error: 'std::ostream& list<T>::operator<<(std::ostream&, const list<T>&)' must take exactly one argumentmain.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:151: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << l'
/usr/include/c++/4.4/ostream:108: note: candidates are: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
... other errors
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

So, here's my question.  What do I need to do to make this work?  I was trying to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549930/c-equivalent-of-java-tostring) as an example.

Comment: Please use Markdown, not HTML. 3½ years is more than sufficient time to learn how to format posts on Stack Overflow... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a combination of `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>` and the suggested `ostream& operator <<` method.

Answer (score 2):

Your `operator<<` is declared as a member function. You need to make it a free function instead, i.e. define it outside the class:

```
template <class T>
class list {
    // ...
};

template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream &o, const list<T>& l) 
{
    // ...
};
```

If you need to make your `operator<<` a friend of the class then please have a look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13464246/1030301)

Also, I noticed that you're using  `ostream` without `std::`, implying that you're using `using namespace std`.

If you're doing that, then it's a really bad idea to call your class `list`, since there is a `std::list` that will be pulled into scope by `using namespace std` if `#include <list>` is added to the file at any time in the future.

Comment: Or just put `friend` in-front of the definition inside the class (no need to move it out).

Comment: @LokiAstari true, that does work, but it's abuse of the `friend` keyword to place the `operator<<` overload in a different scope. So by [the principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), I wouldn't recommend actually doing it.

Comment: @je4d: where did you learn that it's an abuse of `friend`? I've always preferred leaving the declaration as a friend inside the class.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to make the operator<< function as friend?

```
....;
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &o, const list<T>& l) {
....;
```

This is because as shown in the other question, this function has to be declared as a free function, if declared as a member of list, it is only used if it is actually called on a list object itself.

---

#### Edit

Good catch by @je4d.

Looking at your code it looks like you dont need the operator to be a friend since im guessing you will have accessors for head and tail. It would be easier to just declare and define it outside the class as a templated free function.