# Error happens when use friend function to manipulate private variables in template class in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, friend

I am writing a matrix operation library recently.And I want to overload operator s in my program, but Error happened when I use friend function to access private variables in the template class I was defined. (And it reports error only when I overload the operator '+', and the overload function of operation '-' doesn't report error.)
the template class I defined is below:

```
template<class T>
class Matrix
{
    int col;
    int row;
    T *matrix;
    public:
        Matrix(T *m, int row1, int col1):matrix(m), row(row1), col(col1){}
        Matrix(int row1, int col1):row(row1), col(col1)
        {
            matrix = new T[row*col];
            cout<<"Have set the shape of the matrix, but should use create() to initialize the matrix!"<<endl;
        }
        Matrix(){}
        ~Matrix(){}
        void show();
        UINT create(T *m);
        UINT zeros(int size);
        UINT eye(int size);

        // the overload function statement
        friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix &a, const Matrix &b);
        friend Matrix operator-(const Matrix &a, const Matrix &b);

        Matrix matrix_T();              // transpose the matrix
        Matrix matrix_Inv();            // calculate matrix's inverse
        Matrix matrix_Adjoint();        // calculate the adjoint matrix
};
```

And the defination of this two overload functions are below:

```
// report error: can't access private member declared in class
template<class T>
Matrix<T> operator +(const Matrix<T> &m1, const Matrix<T> &m2)
{
    if (m1.col!=m2.col || m1.row!=m2.row)
    {
        cout<<"These two matrices can't be plused!"<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    T *tmp = new T[m1.col*m1.row];
    for (int i=0; i<m1.row; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<m1.col; j++)
        {
            tmp[i*m1.col+j] = m1.matrix[i*m1.col+j] + m2.matrix[i*m1.col+j];
        }
    }
    return Matrix<T>(tmp, m1.row, m1.col);
}


// this defination didn't report error
// and if I only run this code, there is nothing wrong
template<class T>
Matrix<T> operator -(const Matrix<T> &m1, const Matrix<T> &m2)
{
    if (m1.col!=m2.col || m1.row!=m2.row)
    {
        cout<<"These two matrices can't be plused!"<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    T *tmp = new T[m1.col*m1.row];
    for (int i=0; i<m1.row; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<m1.col; j++)
        {
            tmp[i*m1.col+j] = m1.matrix[i*m1.col+j] - m2.matrix[i*m1.col+j];
        }
    }
    return Matrix<T>(tmp, m1.row, m1.col);
}
```

I've tested these two pieces of code seperately, the overload of operator '-' can be compiled correctly, but operator '+' can't. 
The error imformations are below:

```
f:\program\c++\matrixoperate\matrixdefine.h(134) : error C2248: 'col' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Matrix<int>'
    f:\program\c++\matrixoperate\matrixdefine.h(6) : see declaration of 'col'
    f:\program\c++\matrixoperate\demo.cpp(14) : see reference to function template instantiation 'class Matrix<int> __cdecl operator +(const class Matrix<int> &,const class Matrix<int> &)' being compiled
f:\program\c++\matrixoperate\matrixdefine.h(134) : error C2248: 'col' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Matrix<int>'
    f:\program\c++\matrixoperate\matrixdefine.h(6) : see declaration of 'col'
```

And the IDE I use is VC++6.0.

Comment: The problem is that you are using a type variable to bind a specific type to an operator overload, this doesn't make sense as you are using a type argument from a class declaration. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660123/overloading-friend-operator-for-template-class/4661372)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I didn't bind a type variable to operator when I declare it the class. And the overload of operator '-' can run correctly separately. And can you give me some advice on how to correct it?

Comment: Note that vc6 is _incredibly_ limited, particularly in regards to c++ templates. You would be well served by switching to a newer compiler even for introductory work.a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix &a, const Matrix &b);` is not a template.  It is a non template friend function of a template class.

`template<class T>Matrix<T> operator +(const Matrix<T> &m1, const Matrix<T> &m2)` is a template.  They are not the same function, as one is a template the other is not.

The easiest way to fix this is to put the body inline in the template class definition.

The second easiest way is to forward from `operator+` to some static method, or some named function template.  Forward declare it before the template class definition, friend it in the template class definition, implement it afterwarss.

(You actually want `operator+` to be a non-template friend of a template class, as that makes it play much nicer with conversions.)

So do https://stackoverflow.com/a/13464246/1774667 but for a named function, not an operator.  Call it `add`.

Then  `friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix &a, const Matrix &b){ return add(a,b); }` which gives you the non-template friend operator of template class magic.