# Can I silence the warning in a comparison like (myUnsigned >= MACRO_THAT_IS_ZERO) by being more explicit?

Tags: c++, clang

I'm using the clang-based compiler in C++ Builder XE8 (`--version` reports it as `Embarcadero Technologies Inc. clang version 3.1 (35091.dcc1b50.3081e8f) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)`).

My code contains comparisons of unsigned integral values with macros, in the vein of `myUnsignedInt >= MY_MACRO`, which can generate always-true or always-false warnings when `MY_MACRO` is `0`. I know clang has ways to silence certain other warnings by being in some way explicit about your intentions -- `if (foo = bar)` warns, but `if ((foo = bar))` doesn't -- so is there a way to be explicit about a comparison like this (in clang specifically)?

Comment: Have you considered writing code that makes sense?

Comment: @EJP Having an `x >= MIN_VALID_VALUE && x <= MAX_VALID_VALUE` in generic code makes perfect sense, even if in the concrete case it turns out that the types involved aren't signed and `MIN_VALID_VALUE` can be determined at compile time to be zero.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297609/overloading-friend-operator-for-template-class

Answer (score 0):

Is there a  reason why you're using macro's instead of `const int MY_CONSTANT` ?

There's no formal way to silence warnings. Compilers could warn you about your use of whitespace, if they'd want to. Thus the `const` suggestion isn't a guarantee that the warning will be solved. However, macro's are a literal replacement, so the compiler doesn't even know why it sees the pointless statement `if (x>=0)`, whereas it does see `if (x>=c)` with `c==0` so it at least has a better understanding.

Comment: I'm asking about clang and its warnings specifically (sorry if that wasn't clear). Hence the analogy to the assignment in the `if` body, for which an equivalent, more explicit form is specifically understood as a sort of "_sic_".

Answer (score 0):

Try using a helper function, something like this:

```
bool ge(unsigned a, unsigned b) { return a >= b; }
...
  if (ge(num, 0u)) ...
```

It should be optimized away as trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a generic programming approach to using `#pragma` directives.
I ended up defining something like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<class X,bool b>struct NegativeClass{
  static bool test(X x);};
template<class X>struct NegativeClass<X,0>{
  static bool test(X){return 0;}};
template<class X>struct NegativeClass<X,1>{
  static bool test(X x){return x<0;}};
template<class X>bool negative(X x){
  return NegativeClass<X,std::is_signed<X>::value>::test(x);}
```

Now you can use this code fragment:

```
if(negative(x))throw "Error : x is negative";
```

This works when `x` is a built-in type, whether `x` is signed (in which case it does the test) or unsigned (which compiles `if(0)...`).  This sort of approach can be adapted to other situations.